# Getting the last row of sqlite duplicated

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to fetch all the rows from sqlite table as `ArrayList`
i stored successfully four rows in table (id INTEGER, title TEXT, image BLOB)
but when I try to fetch and display these four row i get only the last row duplicated
this is my Model..

```
public class FileUploaded {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private Bitmap image;

    public FileUploaded(int id, String title, Bitmap img){
        this.id=id;
        this.title=title;
        this.image=img;
    }
    public FileUploaded(){}

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title=title;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public void setImage(Bitmap img){
        this.image=img;
    }
    public Bitmap getImage(){
        return image;
    }
}
```

and this is my fetch function..

```
public ArrayList<FileUploaded> getFiles(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<FileUploaded> results = new ArrayList<>();
    FileUploaded file = new FileUploaded();
    Cursor cs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM files",null);
    if (cs.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cs.isAfterLast() == false) {
            file.setId(cs.getInt(cs.getColumnIndex("id")));
            file.setTitle(cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex("title")));
            file.setImage(BitmapUtility.getImage(cs.getBlob(cs.getColumnIndex("image"))));
            results.add(file);
            cs.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

and this is my display function

```
ArrayList<FileUploaded> tst = db.getFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i<tst.size();i++){
                FileUploaded file = tst.get(i);
                Log.w("Display :", "id="+file.getId()+" title="+file.getTitle());

            }
```

hope u can help me guys..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `FileUploaded` object for each iteration in your loop. Now you're updating the values in the same object, and add it again to your array.

In other words, move the

```
FileUploaded file = new FileUploaded();
```

inside the `while` loop.